# how to deal with Element is already the child of another element?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

```
stkpnl = New StackPanel
stkpnl.Children.Add(pan)

mypop = New Popup
mypop.Child = New PopupSubitem
mypop.FlowDirection = System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight

Dim brd As New Border
brd.BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
brd.BorderThickness = New Thickness(5.0)
brd.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
brd.Height = 800
brd.Width = 480
brd.Child = stkpnl

mypop.Child = brd
mypop.VerticalOffset = 250
mypop.HorizontalOffset = 0
mypop.IsOpen = True
```

I am getting problem is this code

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Element is already the child of another element.
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Comment: I suspect the error is in this line : `stkpnl.Children.Add(pan);`. If that is the case, it means `pan` already a children of another element, so you can't add it to `stkpnl` before removing it from it's previous parent